# C++ structure inheritance item system

Tags: inheritance, struct

I am trying to make an item system for a side project and am testing inheritance in structures. This did not give me the intended result:

```
struct Item
{
  int price;
  int id;
};

struct Iron : Item
{
  int price = 10;
  int id = 1;
};

struct Gold : Item
{
  int price = 15;
  int id = 2;
};

int main() 
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  Item testItem = Iron();
  std::cout << "Item price: " << testItem.price << ", Item ID: " << testItem.id << std::endl;
  testItem = Gold();
  std::cout << "Item price: " << testItem.price << ", Item ID: " << testItem.id << std::endl;
}
```

*consule output:*

```
Hello World!
Item price: 0, Item ID: 0
Item price: 0, Item ID: 0
```

Any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override a member variable is not allowed in C++.

When you declare `Iron::price`, you hide `Item::price` in it.

Do things like this:

```
struct Item
{
    int price;
    int id;
};

struct Iron : Item
{
    Iron() {price = 10, id = 1; }
};

struct Gold : Item
{
    Gold() { price = 15, id = 2; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Item testItem = Iron();
    std::cout << "Item price: " << testItem.price << ", Item ID: " << testItem.id << std::endl;
    testItem = Gold();
    std::cout << "Item price: " << testItem.price << ", Item ID: " << testItem.id << std::endl;
}
```

> In your code,
>
> There are four variables in `Iron` : `Item::price`, `Item::id`, `Iron::price`, `Iron::id`
>
> In `Iron::Iron()` you modified `Iron::price` and `Iron::id`, but you output is `Item::price`, `Item::id`.